# How to change class with jQuery at different times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hidden div that is being toggled. When it appears a span gets its class changed.

```
$('#websites').click(function(){
   $('#webthumbs').slideToggle('fast');
   $('#websites span').removeClass('icon-chevron-right').addClass('icon-chevron-down');
   $(this).addClass('open');
});
```

When the div is collapsed and hidden again, I need to change the span's class back to what it was originally. I tried this but it does not work:

```
$('#websites.open').click(function(){
   $('#websites span').removeClass('icon-chevron-down').addClass('icon-chevron-right');
   $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

I have a feeling the second piece of code is not working because `.open` is not in the DOM when the script is loaded. How can I get the second chunk of code to work?

Comment: have you tried checking for the `open` class using `.hasClass`? This can help with debugging

Comment: Have you tried `$('body').on("click", "#websites.open", (function(){...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to toggle the classes to toggle the icon

```
$('#websites').click(function(){
   $('#webthumbs').slideToggle('fast');
   $('#websites span').toggleClass('icon-chevron-right icon-chevron-down');
});
```

The reason the code doesn't work, is because event handlers are added to elements matching the selector at *execution time*, adding the class later makes no difference.

If you need to toggle things that jQuery doesn't provide built-in methods for, you can use a flag

```
$('#websites').click(function(){

    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    if ( flag ) {
        // do anything when the state is "open"
        $('#webthumbs').slideUp('fast');
    } else {
        // do anything when the state is "closed"
        $('#webthumbs').slideDown('fast');        
    }

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the simplest solution so I chose it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Use a delegate

You can use separate state-based event handlers via event delegation. Instead of binding either event to the `#websites` element, bind the event handlers to the nearest stable parent (I'm using `'body'` here, but you may want to use a different selector):

```
$('body').on('click', '#websites:not(.open)', function () {
  ...executed when not open...
}).on('click', '#websites.open', function () {
  ...executed when open...
});
```

The delegate syntax will allow the click callback to be called on the `#websites.open` element despite it not existing in the DOM at the time of binding.

This form is particularly useful when you have significantly different behaviors between the two states.

---

## Use a single callback

If you're just toggling everything, I'd recommend making use of jQuery's toggle functions and do it all in one go:

```
$('#websites').on('click', function () {
  $(this)
    .slideToggle('fast')
    .toggleClass('open')
    .find('span')
      .toggleClass('icon-chevron-right icon-chevron-down');
});
```

If you have separate functionality between the two states, you can use a simple `if .is` check:

```
$('#websites').on('click', function () {
  if ($(this).is('.open')) {
    $(this)
      .removeClass('open')
      ...
  } else {
    $(this)
      .addClass('open')
      ...
  }
});
```

---

## Toggle multiple callbacks

You can expose callbacks as function references, and toggle which ones are active at any given time:

```
function openWebsites() {
  $(this)
    .off('click', openWebsites)
    .on('click', closeWebsites)
    .addClass('open')
    ...
}
function closeWebsites() {
  $(this)
    .off('click', closeWebsites)
    .on('click', openWebsites)
    .removeClass('open')
    ...
}
$('#websites').on('click', openWebsites);
```

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the previous answers, you could consolidate the two click handlers into one:

```
$('#websites').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $('#websites span')
            .removeClass('icon-chevron-down')
            .addClass('icon-chevron-right');
    } else {
        $('#webthumbs').slideToggle('fast');
        $('#websites span')
            .removeClass('icon-chevron-right')
            .addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- When you click and the `open` class **is not** part of your clicked element, do something.
- When you click and the `open` class **is** part of your clicked element, do otherwise.

By putting it into words you can see the similarity: Your click event is common among both actuons, this is what needs to happen only once. Within this click event you can use jQuery's **[hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)** function to separate the purpose of your click events.

I took the liberty of optimizing your code a little by using caching for your variables. Let me know if you have any questions in the comments below.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#websites').click(function() {
    var websites = $(this),
        webthumbs = $("#webthumbs"),
        websitesSpan = $("#websites span");

    webthumbs.slideToggle('fast');

    if (websites.hasClass("open")) {
      websitesSpan.removeClass('icon-chevron-down').addClass('icon-chevron-right');
      websites.removeClass('open');
    } else {
      websitesSpan.removeClass('icon-chevron-right').addClass('icon-chevron-down');
      websites.addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```